# using SequenceHold as an argument to a Function

Tags: functions, function-construction

I had always wondered whether it is possible for a single argument of `Function` to hold multiple values i.e. can `Function[x,foo[x]][1,2,3]` somehow produce `foo[1,2,3]`? In its current form the values `2` and `3` are discarded and we obtain `foo[1]`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this much more easily using `SlotSequence`.

```
f = p[##] &
f[1, 2, 3]
(*p[1,2,3]*)

g = q[#,{##2}]&
g[1,2,3]
(* q[1,{2,3}] *)
```

Comment: agreed :) i already knew that this was the simplest method. In my answer i only wanted to highlight the attribute `SequenceHold`.

Answer (score 3):

We can conveniently do it using `SequenceHold` as the function attribute and passing the values with a head `Sequence` to the `Function`

```
Function[{x}, p@x, SequenceHold][Sequence[1, 2, 3]]
(* p[1, 2, 3] *)
```

we can make a small function:

```
h[y___][p_Symbol] := Function[{x}, p@x, SequenceHold][Sequence[y]];

h[1,2,3][p]
(* p[1,2,3] *)
```